# Why the text generated from the previous table row of number cannot be displayed in the next table row?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Here's another problem encountered with js/html code. I typed some numbers at the top of the page, then after I pressed the button `First Line`, it will display the numbers I inputted in the first table row accordingly. If I press the button `Last Line`, I'd like it to display some numbers after getting done with some arithmetics, which is in the `btn2` part in the js file, in the last table row of the page. I'd like to find out if it is the problem of `innerHTML` or `valueAsNumber` in the `if` statements, or the `variables` declared in the `for` loop not applicable in the later `if` statements, that caused the numbers in the last row cannot be displayed eventually.

The for loop and the if statement is intended for the page to scan the numbers inputted in the first row, do some arithmetics with them, and display them in the last row, in each respective cell. Is there any other way out to do so?

Thank you very much!

```js
const tab = document.getElementById("tab");

const btn1 = document.getElementById('btn1');
const btn2 = document.getElementById('btn2');

var R1 = [R1C1, R1C2, R1C3, R1C4, R1C5, R1C6, R1C7, R1C8,
  R1C9, R1C10, R1C11, R1C12, R1C13, R1C14, R1C15, R1C16];
var R2 = [R2C1, R2C2, R2C3, R2C4, R2C5, R2C6, R2C7, R2C8,
  R2C9, R2C10, R2C11, R2C12, R2C13, R2C14, R2C15, R2C16];

btn1.addEventListener('click', () => {
  for (var i = 0; i <= 15; i++) {
    let row = tab.rows[1];
    let c = row.cells[i];
    let inpId = 'inp' + (i + 1);
    let inpEl = document.getElementById(inpId);
    c.innerHTML = inpEl.value;
  }
});

btn2.addEventListener('click', () => {
  for (var i = 0; i <= 15; i++) {
    var r1c = R1[i].id;
    var r2c = R2[i].id;
    var r1El = document.getElementById(r1c);
    var r2El = document.getElementById(r2c);
  }

  if (r1El.innerHTML > 0) {
    var choices = [0, (r1El.valueAsNumber) % 7, (r1El.valueAsNumber + 2) % 7, (r1El.valueAsNumber - 2) % 7];
    var x = Math.floor(Math.random() * choices.length);

    if (choices[x] == choices.at(0)) {
      r2El.innerHTML = choices[x];
    } else if (choices[x] <= 0) {
      r2El.innerHTML = choices[x] + 7;
    }
  }
});
```

```css
th,
tr,
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 5px;
  width: 40px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div id="data">
    <table id="inpdata">
      <tr>
        <td id="inpb1">Group 1</td>
        <td id="inpb2">Group 2</td>
        <td id="inpb3">Group 3</td>
        <td id="inpb4">Group 4</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <input type="number" id="inp1" title="inp1">
          <input type="number" id="inp2" title="inp2">
          <input type="number" id="inp3" title="inp3">
          <input type="number" id="inp4" title="inp4">
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="number" id="inp5" title="inp5">
          <input type="number" id="inp6" title="inp6">
          <input type="number" id="inp7" title="inp7">
          <input type="number" id="inp8" title="inp8">
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="number" id="inp9" title="inp9">
          <input type="number" id="inp10" title="inp10">
          <input type="number" id="inp11" title="inp11">
          <input type="number" id="inp12" title="inp12">
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="number" id="inp13" title="inp13">
          <input type="number" id="inp14" title="inp14">
          <input type="number" id="inp15" title="inp15">
          <input type="number" id="inp16" title="inp16">
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <br>
    <button id="btn1">First line</button>
    <button id="btn2">Last line</button>
  </div>

  <div id="tables">
    <table id="tab">
      <tr>
        <th colspan="4">Group 1</th>
        <th colspan="4">Group 2</th>
        <th colspan="4">Group 3</th>
        <th colspan="4">Group 4</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td id="R1C1"></td>
        <td id="R1C2"></td>
        <td id="R1C3"></td>
        <td id="R1C4"></td>
        <td id="R1C5"></td>
        <td id="R1C6"></td>
        <td id="R1C7"></td>
        <td id="R1C8"></td>
        <td id="R1C9"></td>
        <td id="R1C10"></td>
        <td id="R1C11"></td>
        <td id="R1C12"></td>
        <td id="R1C13"></td>
        <td id="R1C14"></td>
        <td id="R1C15"></td>
        <td id="R1C16"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td id="R2C1"></td>
        <td id="R2C2"></td>
        <td id="R2C3"></td>
        <td id="R2C4"></td>
        <td id="R2C5"></td>
        <td id="R2C6"></td>
        <td id="R2C7"></td>
        <td id="R2C8"></td>
        <td id="R2C9"></td>
        <td id="R2C10"></td>
        <td id="R2C11"></td>
        <td id="R2C12"></td>
        <td id="R2C13"></td>
        <td id="R2C14"></td>
        <td id="R2C15"></td>
        <td id="R2C16"></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
```

Comment: `I'd like to find out of the problem is...` but what have you done to debug it? Is there an error in your console?

Comment: The loop inside btn2 click handler code...doesn't do anything.  Not sure what the intention is there.

Comment: @mykaf I tried to replace `innerHTML` with `innerText` or `valueAsNumber`, and there is still nothing happened. The console gives no error at all, it's just that the text didn't appear in the last row.

Comment: @James I would like the page to check all the cells in row 1, see what's the number inputted, do some arithmetic with the if statements, before displaying the new numbers in the same "column" or "cell" in the last table row.

Comment: I have a theory about your intentions: For each group, for each column you want to display the result of a function given the value of the above cell. Is this correct?

Comment: @Simon Yes! That's my intention.

Comment: What are `R1C1,...R2C16` in `R1` and `R2`?

Comment: @Julia If the answer provided solves your problem, you can accept it. If it is not, please try to rephrase your Question

Comment: @Simon I'm sorry that I haven't tried implementing your code into tests, such that I have't ticked the box and scored your answer. Working on it now. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you can Iterate the td by iterating the `elements` HTMLCollection property of the tr. Iterate two Iterables by using the index from one.

```js
const tab = document.getElementById("tab");

const btn1 = document.getElementById('btn1');
const btn2 = document.getElementById('btn2');

const firstRow = tab.firstElementChild.children[1].children;
const secondRow = tab.firstElementChild.children[2].children;

btn1.addEventListener('click', () => {
  for (var i = 0; i <= 7 /* <- This is a magic value - avoid these */; i++) {
    let row = tab.rows[1];
    let c = row.cells[i];
    let inpId = 'inp' + (i + 1);
    let inpEl = document.getElementById(inpId);
    c.innerHTML = inpEl.value;
  }
});

btn2.addEventListener('click', () => {
    [...secondRow].forEach((el,index)=>{
        //let group = Math.floor(index / 4);
        
        let inp = parseInt(firstRow[index].innerText, 10);
        
        if (!inp) return;

        let choices = [0, inp, (inp + 2), (inp - 2)];
        let x = (Math.floor(Math.random() * choices.length) + 7) % 7;
        
        el.innerText = x;
    })
});
```

```css
th,
tr,
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 5px;
  width: 40px;
  height: 1.5em;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div id="data">
    <table id="inpdata">
      <tr>
        <td id="inpb1">Group 1</td>
        <td id="inpb2">Group 2</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <input type="number" id="inp1" title="inp1">
          <input type="number" id="inp2" title="inp2">
          <input type="number" id="inp3" title="inp3">
          <input type="number" id="inp4" title="inp4">
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="number" id="inp5" title="inp5">
          <input type="number" id="inp6" title="inp6">
          <input type="number" id="inp7" title="inp7">
          <input type="number" id="inp8" title="inp8">
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <br>
    <button id="btn1">First line</button>
    <button id="btn2">Last line</button>
  </div>

  <div id="tables">
    <table id="tab">
      <tr>
        <th colspan="4">Group 1</th>
        <th colspan="4">Group 2</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td>
        <td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td>
        <td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
```

Some additional advice:
I couldn't be bothered to clean up all of your code, next time please provide a Minimal Example, tree fields would have been plenty to ask the question.

Further please avoid magic numbers, like you use in your loops. Get the size of what you are iterating when you use it. This makes your code more flexible and reusable.

In the same vein: Please do not throw ids everywhere. They just beg to break your code if you ever try to reuse it somehow.